# Regex to replace the character after pattern match

Tags: java, regex, replace

For my Java app, i have a string that looks like:

```
value1: *sample", test
test: "test"
newtest: *newtest"
```

I need to match the character `"` when the string starts with `*`.
Tried the regex:
`"(?!.*")`
But this selected all the `"` in the input.
Was planning to `replaceAll(regex, "")` to remove the character.

Desired Output:

```
value1: *sample, test
test: "test"
newtest: *newtest
```

How do i get this output?

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("(\\*\\w+)\"", "$1")`

Comment: This worked, Thanks. I can see that you are matching the word starting with `*` and ending with `"`, how did the `"` get replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.replaceAll("(\\*\\w+)\"", "$1")
```

*Details*:

- `(\*\w+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to the text captured in this group)
- `"` - a `"` char (just matched, not captured, so eventually removed).